# I want to modify the content of log file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

log file looks like
`07-15:01:07:690848 |1------>  5 AeradminAsst 293103381  |  <OpenIdmAssetMarketTradeEvent xRogType="25" BookingType="1" ContraClearingFirm="2781" ExchExecID="2781.5000002000" ExecID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2" ExecType="F" ExecutingFirm="Aeris"  MsgType="8" OrderCapacity="P"   OrigExecID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2"    ExternalCustomerAccountSDSID="425e2e91"  UniqueTradeId="AERADMINASSET-147-8667655360141328392" MIFIDTradingCapacity="0" OrdType="2" ReportableEntity="12345678" pb_version="trunk-35310"></OpenIdmMarketTradeEvent> | !STOCK/TRADE01/USA/QPA/SUB/PACM001`

Now I have to modify the content of it like below . I need to add start html tag and copy ExecID to ExecRefID and then modify the value of ExecID by appending "PUSH_"  . also I need to change the value ExecType from F to H

```
07-15:01:07:690848 |1------>  5 AeradminAsst 293103381  |  <OpenIdmAssetMarketTradeEvent xRogType="25" BookingType="1" ContraClearingFirm="2781" ExchExecID="2781.5000002000" ExecID="CANCEL_USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2" ExecType="H" ExecutingFirm="Aeris"  MsgType="8" OrderCapacity="P"   OrigExecID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2"    ExternalCustomerAccountSDSID="425e2e91"  UniqueTradeId="AERADMINASSET-147-8667655360141328392" MIFIDTradingCapacity="0" OrdType="2" ReportableEntity="12345678" ExecRefID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2" pb_version="trunk-35310"></OpenIdmMarketTradeEvent> | !STOCK/TRADE01/USA/QPA/SUB/SUBM001
```

script should handle huge block of logs

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ 
   printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", 
     "<START>", 
     gensub(/(.*) (ExecID=)"(.*)" (.*)/,"\\1 \\2\"PUSH_\\3\" type=\"OK\" TRANID=\"\\3\"", 1, $0), 
     "</START>"
}' logfile


<START>
07-15:01:56 ClientID="422314" ComplianceID="skdjiowecn33nf" ExecID="PUSH_343ndndn8c" type="OK" TRANID="343ndndn8c"
</START>
<START>
07-15:01:57 ClientID="422e214" ComplianceID="skdjiowecn33nf" ExecID="PUSH_34en3fn" type="OK" TRANID="34en3fn"
</START>
<START>
07-15:01:58 ClientID="42124" ComplianceID="skdjiowecn33nf" ExecID="PUSH_4n23n43" type="OK" TRANID="4n23n43"
</START>
```

---

```
07-15:01:56 ClientID="422314" ComplianceID="skdjiowecn33nf" ExecID="343ndndn8c" Type="NOK"
----------------------------------------------------------- ------- ----------  ----------
                            |                                  |    | (.*) group3 \\3 | (.*) group4 \\4
match-groups         (.*) group1 \\1                           |
                                                            (ExecID=) group2 \\2
```

Update for the second log:

```
awk '
    {
    gsub(/>/, " >")
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        split($i, a, "=")
        attrib=a[1]
        value=gensub(/"/,"","g",a[2])

        if(attrib == "ExecID"){
            $i = attrib"=\"CANCEL_"value"\""
            execid=value
        }

        if(attrib == "ExecType"){
            if (value == "F") $i = attrib"=\"H\""
        }

        if(attrib == "lm_version"){
            $i = "pb_version=\""value"\""
        }

        if(attrib == "MIDTradingCapacity"){
            $i = "MIFIDTradingCapacity=\""value"\""
            $i = $i " OrdType=\"2\""
        }

        if(attrib == "ReportableEntity"){
            $i = $i " ExecRefID=\""execid "\""
        }
    }
    gsub(/ >/, ">")
    $0 = "<START>\n"$0"\n</START>"
}1' logfile
```

```
<START>
07-15:01:07:690848 |1------> 5 AeradminAsst 293103381 | <OpenIdmAssetMarketTradeEvent xRogType="25" BookingType="1" ContraClearingFirm="2781" ExchExecID="2781.5000002000" ExecID="CANCEL_USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2" ExecType="H" ExecutingFirm="Aeris" MsgType="8" OrderCapacity="P" OrigExecID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2" ExternalCustomerAccountSDSID="425e2e91" UniqueTradeId="AERADMINASSET-147-8667655360141328392" MIFIDTradingCapacity="0" OrdType="2" ReportableEntity="12345678" ExecRefID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2" pb_version="trunk-35310"></OpenIdmMarketTradeEvent> | !STOCK/TRADE01/USA/QTA/MAC/TOTAL001
</START>
```

Comment: can you pls explain the \\1 \\3 part . I need to further modify it

Comment: @A.Ranjan. i added the groups in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your info. Is there is any thing to replace the word in gensub
```gensub(/(.*) (ExecID=)"(.*)" (ExecType=)"(.*)" / ,"\\1 \\2\"CANCEL_\\3\" \\4\"H\\5\" ExecRefID=\"\\3\" ", 1, $0), ```
I wanted to replace ExecType value with "H" but in above command , It appends H followed by  the value which is already there in ExecType.

Comment: @A.Ranjan The ExecType value is group 5 -->  \\5.   You have to remove \\5 here `\\4\"H\\5\"`

Comment: I did that but when I remove \\5 all others trailing line logs gets removed and it prints out till ExecType=H . In original there are others lines as well which I need to be printed . I tried `gensub(/(.*) (ExecID=)"(.*)" (ExecType=)"(.*)" (.* )/,"\\1 \\2\"CANCEL_\\3\" \\4\"H\" ExecRefID=\"\\3\"  \\6", 1, $0)  but still last lines are not getting printed . Please help

Comment: @A.Ranjan. can you post your log again?..

Comment: -->
`07-15:01:07:690848 |1------>  5 AeradminAsst 293103381  |  <OpenIdmAssetMarketTradeEvent xRogType="25" BookingType="1" ContraClearingFirm="2781" ExchExecID="2781.5000002000" ExecID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2" ExecType="F" ExecutingFirm="Aeris"  MsgType="8" OrderCapacity="P"   OrigExecID="USACO1781000621220607!2781.N.wS.B.F7T/e2"    ExternalCustomerAccountSDSID="425e2e91"  UniqueTradeId="AERADMINASSET-147-8667655360141328392" MIDTradingCapacity="0" ReportableEntity="12345678" lm_version="trunk-35310"></OpenIdmMarketTradeEvent> | !STOCK/TRADE01/USA/QTA/MAC/TOTAL001`

Comment: @A.Ranjan. and the desired output?.. Can you  append all this in the original question?

Comment: --> I have edited the original query with actual logs

Comment: @A.Ranjan.. plz test it.. what is the  OrdType???

Comment: --> Now its changing as per the requirement. Thanks